# Криво выводится текст при использовании цикла и AWT

Tags: java, awt

Только приступил к изучению графических библиотек Java, начав с AWT, и решил поэкспериментировать. Написал такой код:

```
public class Main extends Frame{

    String[] names = {"Миша", "Владимир", "Александр", "Маша", "Григорий", "Роман", "Антон"};
    int y=40;

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        setSize(640, 480);
        for (int i = 0; i<names.length; i++){
            g.drawString(names[i], 10, y);
            y+=20;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Но выводятся имена вот так:
[image: Но выводятся имена вот так:]

В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод paint(Graphics g) вызывается каждый раз когда требуется перерисовать компонент. Например при изменении размеров, перемещении и т.д. 
Следовательно `y` начинается со значения 40 только на первой итерации. При последующих перерисовках там будет (40 + длинна массива * 20) * номер перерисовки. 
Устанавливайте начальное значение `y` в начале метода paint:

```
@Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        y = 40;
        for (int i = 0; i<names.length; i++){
            g.drawString(names[i], 10, y);
            y+=20;
        }
    }
```

Кроме того не правильно устанавливать размер окна в методе paint. Делайте это в методе main:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.setSize(640, 480);
        main.setVisible(true);
    }
```